# Unable to store data into firebase database

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

Help, I cant save my data in firebase realtime database, it keeps my app force close. Please help im new at android.

```
private void SReport(){
    String name = etfulln.getText().toString().trim();
    String reason = etreason.getText().toString().trim();
    String address = etaddr.getText().toString().trim();
    String contact = etcontn.getText().toString().trim();

    if (!TextUtils.isEmpty(name) && !TextUtils.isEmpty(reason) && !TextUtils.isEmpty(address) && !TextUtils.isEmpty(contact)){
        String id = DBReport.push().getKey();
        Report report = new Report(id,name,reason,address,contact);
        DBReport.child(id).setValue(report);
        Toast.makeText(this, "Report added", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
    else{
        Toast.makeText(this, "Fill details", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
}
```

Comment: have you initialize DBReport in oncreate?

Comment: I declare it as a new Databasereference

Comment: can you show me the complete code?

Comment: EditText etfulln,etreason,etaddr,etcontn;
Button btsave;
DatabaseReference DBReport;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_report_main);
        etfulln = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.etfulln);
        etreason = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.etreason);
        etaddr = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.etaddr);
        etcontn = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.etcontn);
        btsave = (Button)findViewById(R.id.btsave);

Comment: DBReport = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("Report");

        btsave.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
            SReport();
            }
        });
    }

Comment: ok can you send me log error?

Comment: I dont have error sir, it keeps force close if i press the save button

Comment: I use my phone when running it

Comment: ok have you declare internet permission in manifest file?

Comment: I dont know that sir.

Comment: ok dont worry about it , I am sending you link that will help you how read,write and delete data from firebase realtime database please do refer these. 1.https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=EM2x33g4syY&list=PLk7v1Z2rk4hj6SDHf_YybDeVhUT9MXaj1

Comment: Thank you sir you're a big help to me!

Comment: wc its my pleasure

Comment: make sure that internet connection permission, firebase gradle dependency should be there in your code

Comment: If the app crashes, there is a stack trace. Please look that up on logcat, and add it to your question. Please lso responde with @.